# jQuery Validate Remote redirect page on false

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, redirect, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validate remote to check a php file and see if an email address is already in use. It works fine, however, I need it to redirect to a new page IF the email typed in already exists or "false". Below is the working remote validate script and simple php file.  Again this works fine, just not sure how to redirect to a new page if the php script returns false.

```
     rules: {
            fullname: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "validate-email.php",
                    type: "post",
                },
            },

    messages: {
     email: {
        required: 'Please enter a valid email address',
        remote: 'Sorry, this email address is already in use',
        }
    }
```

validate-email.php

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        // A user with this email address already exists
        echo 'false';
    }else{
        echo 'true';
    }
}
```

Just to mention it one last time, the above php and jquery script work fine.  Just need to redirect to a new page if the php result is echo 'false';

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342716/jquery-validation-form-remote-rule-success-message) will help? This should allows you to retrieve a server response. Effectively you need to add a parent: `success: function(e) {}`. the **e** variable is the server's response (ie: "true" or "false"). Within this, you could do `if (e=="true"){}`

Comment: I don't understand the point of this.  The whole point of the validation plugin is to *stop* the submit of the form if/when it's invalid.  If you're echoing a `false` to the `remote` method, then it's an "invalid" form and should not be submitted until the user fixes their input values.   So since you don't care about the user fixing their data and submitting the form, instead of echoing `false`, why not use PHP to just redirect to a new page?

Comment: Thanks TheMintyMate - I was able to do it as you described by simply adding success: function(e) { if(e == false){window.location.replace("http://mywebsite.com");}}

Answer (score 0):

I was able to redirect by simply adding the information from TheMintyMate

```
 rules: {
        fullname: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: "validate-email.php",
                type: "post",
                success: function(e) { if(e == false){window.location.replace("http://website");}}
            },
        },

messages: {
 email: {
    required: 'Please enter a valid email address',
    remote: 'Sorry, this email address is already in use',
    }
}
```