# Stop jQuery Ajax Success from preventing form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validate with remote to check if an email address exists.  Don't ask me why but I need it to redirect to a new page IF a match is found in the database (false), otherwise they should be able to use the form normally.

This code works perfect EXCEPT: if it returns true (meaning it didn't redirect) the form submit button doesn't do anything.  I don't see any attributes assigned like disabled, but the form submission is defintely prevented.  If I don't type anything in the email input, it will let me click the button.

```
        rules: {
            fullname: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "validate-email.php",
                    type: "post",
                    success: function(response) { 
                        if(response === false){
                            window.location.href = 'new-page.html';
                        }
                    },
                },
            },

          },
```

once I remove the success: section, form submission works normally so obviously it has something to do with what I did in there... Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Yeah, as I tried to explain in [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372364/jquery-validate-remote-redirect-page-on-false#comment58450895_35372364) on [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35372364/594235)... use the server-side code to do the redirect on `false`.  By default, when `true` is echoed back from the PHP, the `remote` rule is automatically satisfied.  By using the `success` option, you are breaking this default functionality.

Comment: I created a new question because I thought it would be confusing.  I tried adding it to the php script and it didn't do anything.  Your referring to a simple header(Location: 'new-page.html'); right?

Comment: The validation plugin merges your `remote:` options into its call to `$.ajax`. It has its own `success:` function that processes the response so that it can mark the element valid or invalid. But your `success` function is overriding that, so the validation doesn't work.

Comment: @Sparky How would he do this in the server side of the validation? A redirection of an AJAX call doesn't redirect the client page.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the information.  I am a bit confused however because the validation still works fine, the only issue is my submit button for the form stops working if I type anything in the email input.  I still get the validation response (Green check for ok, or redirect for taken).  Is there another option to success to accomplish the same effect?

Comment: @Barmar, my mistake then.  Otherwise, maybe he can try an `else` with a `return true` or `return response` within the `success` parameter.

Comment: @JoshuaOlds I must have misunderstood the problem. Try Sparky's suggestion.

Comment: I was able to fix it by changing it from success to complete and using data.responseText from another solution i found.  Your information about the remote and it's own success gave me the clue I needed I think :)  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but I was able to fix it by using this:

```
                remote: {
                    url: "validate-email.php",
                    type: "post",
                    complete: function(data) { 
                        if(data.responseText == "false"){
                            window.location.href = 'new-page.php';
                        }else{
                            return response;
                        }
                    },
```

Thank you for your help!